# How can i pick a string from an array to use it in a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

New to javascript, learning for fun. Searched for hours a solution online but no luck
i decided to make a hangman game, the thing is that i cannot figure it out how to make my program choose a word from an array to use it in a function.

```
function iniciar(){
var palabrasas = [
    ["lumetrio", "discord", "ageofempires", "bootcamp", "juego"],
    ["gato","perro","burro","rinoceronte"],
    ["nacho","javier","vicente"]
    ];
var palabra = palabrasas[Math.floor(Math.random() * palabrasas.length )];
var respuesta =[];
for (var i = 0; i < palabra.length; i++) {
    respuesta[i] = " _ ";
}

var letrasrestantes = palabra.length;
while (letrasrestantes > 0) {
    alert(respuesta.join(" "));
    var adivinar = prompt(" Adivina una letra");
    if (adivinar == null) {
        break;
    } else if (adivinar.length !== 1) {
        alert("Pone una sola letra");
    } else {
        for (var j= 0; j < palabra.length; j++) {
            if (palabra[j] === adivinar){
                respuesta[j] = adivinar;
                letrasrestantes--;
            }
        }
    }
}
alert(respuesta.join(" "));
alert("Advinaste, la palabra era: " + palabra);
}
```

the program chooses a full string instead of just a word from it. so when i run it, it picks [lumetrio, discord, ageofempires... etc]
what i want is a way to choose what line of the array to pick a random word from it.
like: palabrasas[0] the word was discord

Comment: `palabrasas` is a 2D array, so you need to access individual elements first by the index of the nested array, then the index of the element. `discord` can be referenced using `palabrasas[0][1]` (the second element in the first nested array)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to pick a random number between 1 and 10

```
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
```

Then this to get the word;

```
var word = palabrasas[index];
```

To improve this you can use (use the length of the palabrasas array

```
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * palabrasas.length);
```

Comment: This is exactly what the OP is already doing, but `palabrasas` is a 2D array, so you'll need a second index based on the length of the array found at the first. `const word = palabrasas[index][secondRandomIndex];`